# ascii codec can't encode character, python 2.6

Tags: python, character-encoding, python-2.x

I know this is a common beginner issue and there are a ton of questions like this here on stack exchange and I've been searching through them but i still can't figure this out.  I have some data from a scrape that looks like this (about 1000 items in the list):

```
inputList = [[u'someplace', u'3901 West Millen Drive', u'Hobbs', u'NH', 
u'88240', u'37.751117', u'-103.187709999'], [u'\u0100lon someplace', u'3120 
S Las Vegas Blvd', u'Las Duman', u'AL', u'89109', u'36.129066', u'-145.168791']]
```

I'm trying to write it to a csv file like this:

```
for i in inputList:
    for ii in i:
        ii.replace(" u'\u2019'", "") #just trying to get rid of offending character
        ii.encode("utf-8")

def csvWrite(inList, outFile):
    import csv
    destination = open(outFile, 'w')
    writer = csv.writer(destination, delimiter = ',')
    data = inList   
    writer.writerows(data)
    destination.close()
csvWrite(inputList, output)
```

but I keep getting this error on, writer.writerows(data):

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in  
position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I've tried a bunch of different thing to encode the data in the list, but still always get the error.  I'm open to just ignoring the characters that can't be encoded to ascii.  Can anyone point me in the right direction, I'm using python2.6

Comment: yes I did mean to do that, but I still get the same error after fixing that line

Answer (score 1):

this line seems strange: `ii.replace(" u'\u2019'", "")`, did you mean `ii.replace(u"\u2019", u"")` ?

Answer (score -1):

if you just want to remove those bad characters you could use this code instead:

```
for i in inputList:
    for ii in i:
        ii = "".join(list( filter((lambda x: ord(x) < 128), ii)))
        print ii
```

Output:

```
someplace
3901 West Millen Drive
Hobbs
NH
88240
37.751117
-103.187709999
lon someplace
3120 S Las Vegas Blvd
Las Duman
AL
89109
36.129066
-145.168791
```

the final code will look like this:

```
inputList = [[u'someplace', u'3901 West Millen Drive', u'Hobbs', u'NH', 
u'88240', u'37.751117', u'-103.187709999'], [u'\u0100lon someplace', u'3120 S Las Vegas Blvd', u'Las Duman', u'AL', u'89109', u'36.129066', u'-145.168791']]

cleared_inputList = []

for i in inputList:
    c_i = []
    for ii in i:
        ii = "".join(list( filter((lambda x: ord(x) < 128), ii)))
        c_i.append(ii)
    cleared_inputList.append(c_i)

def csvWrite(inList, outFile):
    import csv
    destination = open(outFile, 'w')
    writer = csv.writer(destination, delimiter = ',')
    data = inList   
    writer.writerows(data)
    destination.close()


csvWrite(cleared_inputList, output)
```

Comment: @J.Hammond that is because you haven't update `inputList`, i'll edit my answer to do so.

Comment: Thank you that helps.   it doesn't throw the encoding error now and the bad characters are removed from cleared_inputList.  However I still can't get all of the rows to write even when i write from cleared_inputList.   It stops at this item.        
     [u'Billy\u2019s Casino', u'233 West Bennett Avenue', u'Cripple     Creek', u'CO', u'80813', u'38.746838', u'-105.177332500']

Comment: @J.Hammond write what and wich item?

Comment: sorry, i didn't downvote, at least not on purpose, i can't seem to remove it